# Exporting Excel file using spreadsheets gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet

I am trying to export a .xls file from my rail application and can not seem to get it to work. I am new to ruby and rails... Here is a sample of my code...

```
def results
    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    sheet1 = book.create_worksheet do |row|
    row << [ 'name', 'address', 'date', 'amount' ]
    results.each do |r|
    row << [ r.name, r.address, r.date, r.amount ]
    send_data(sheet1, :type => "application/xls", :filename => "#{client.client_id} #{source.source_id} - search results - #{DateTime.now.strftime("%m.%d.%y")}.xls")
end
```

The output I am getting in the xls fils is ... #< Spreadsheet::Worksheet:0x5fb8fd8>

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I still have not been able to solve this problem... does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look the documentation here ?
http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html

Sounds like you're using a mix of the syntax used for reading and writing at the same time.

You should do something like :

```
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1.row(0) << [ 'name', 'address', 'date', 'amount' ]
results.each_with_index do |r, i|
  sheet1.row(i+1) << [ r.name, r.address, r.date, r.amount ]
end
```

I didn't try it, but it shoulnd't be far from what is needed :)

Comment: I tried that and still getting the same out put in the excel file... I get a warning when trying to open the excel file... "The file you are trying to open, [filename.xls] is in a different format than specified by the file extension"?? I have the require in the Gemfile and the encoding on the top of the page... do I need anything else? I am trying to fix another persons code...

Comment: Do you write to the file like this before send_data ? `book.write '/path/to/output/excel-file.xls'`

Comment: I have this in mime_type.rb... Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls

Comment: Well in the send_data instruction you're sending a file, so you should write in the same file before sending it I guess

Comment: I tried the book.write but that does not seem to make a difference... I am getting the exact same output in the excel file... ??